# Taking array input from user

Tags: python

I am facing problem to take number of inputs from user then storing it in an array,how to print this array

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you asking why it prints `<map object at ...>` instead of the contents?

Comment: What is the purpose of `n`?  You never use it.

Comment: @JohnGordon in a lot of programming contest problems, the input often consists of the size of the list `n` followed by `n` numbers so that you can initialize an array of the proper size ahead of time (assuming you aren't using Python).

Comment: This is not the full code,i just want to know what does the second line actually doing and how to print the user input in an array

Comment: Can you give an example of what the input looks like?

Comment: n=5 and arr should be [2,1,6,6,5]

Comment: But what does the *actual* input look like? What are you parsing? What is the user typing in?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `map` takes a function as one argument and a list as the second argument and applies that function to all of the items in the list. The catch is that this application is [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417210/lazy-evaluation-of-map), meaning that it returns a `map` object (which is a generator), and doesn't actually apply the function until you try to iterate through `arr`.

In your case, if you want to print out the contents of `arr`, you can simply do:

`arr = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: Not working,its just printing the first element of the list & nothing else.still thanks